# Applying an attribute to everything in a container ecxept one element

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a checkbox with a couple of selections for a search. I want the selection screen to open up when pressing anywhere, but I dont want it to close when the user selects a checkbox. How would I then remove the data-toggle attribute from the checkboxes?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.2.0/mdb.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>e-commerce</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.2.0/mdb.min.js"></script>


 <div class="card card-body ripple"data-toggle="collapse" href="#filter1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <b>
    Filter 1
</b>
  <div id="filter1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox1"name="filter1_checkbox1">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox2"name="filter1_checkbox2">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox3"name="filter1_checkbox3">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `event.stopPropagation()` to not trigger event into parents input with jquery. As below your code.

```js
$("#filter1").on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.2.0/mdb.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>e-commerce</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.2.0/mdb.min.js"></script>


 <div class="card card-body ripple"data-toggle="collapse" href="#filter1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <b>
    Filter 1
</b>
  <div id="filter1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox1"name="filter1_checkbox1">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox2"name="filter1_checkbox2">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox3"name="filter1_checkbox3">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```